# Refresh a div with JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf, html, refresh

I have two JSF applications.  One gets some data and does some code magic on it and then I output it to a file.  This happens every n seconds.  What I would like to do is have a div or something like it in my second JSF app.  I want to display the contents of this file in the second app.  The trick is how do I refresh this data every n seconds without refreshing the entire page?

Comment: You can do this using a poll component like [`<p:poll>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf) from PrimeFaces. Note that you can build one from scratch using JavaScript and JSF but it is not recommended to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Use Primefaces [Ajax Polling](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf), which can make ajax calls in a specified interval.